# Understanding llvm SelectionDAG

Tags: llvm-ir

For a simple llvm IR as:

```
define i32 @test(i32 %X, i32 %Y) {
    %Z = udiv i32 %X, %Y
    ret i32 %Z
  }
```

the SelectionDAG graph is more complex than I thought:

[image: image of SelectionDAG graph]

Why is `CopyFromReg` needed, why not connect `vreg0` and `vreg1` to `udiv` directly?

How should I read the graph, from `EntryToken` to `GraphRoot` or the opposite direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments are calling convention specific and they are lowered in the construction process of **SelectionDAG** (`SelectionDAGISel::SelectAllBasicBlocks` calls `SelectionDAGISel::LowerArguments`), the architecture specific LowerArguments usually creates `CopyFromReg` to represent the arguments in virtual register as `SDValue` and chain the `CopyFromReg` to **SelectionDAG**.

The extra **CopyFromReg** is attached to maintain the Chain to EntryToken, and store other information which is designed not to be part of `RegisterSDNode`, like `DebugLoc`.

Here is an example that **CopyFromReg** is not attached (blue dotted arrows are missing):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Entry Token is the entry for the function, it is used to "chain" (the blue link) all the operations that have side effects.
I think that the CopyFromReg and CopyToReg are here to implement the calling conventions for the function.

Comment: Any proof that EntryToken is the entry of function? I have question on this since SelectionDAG is for a basic block, not function.

Comment: Well in the given example there is only one basic block in the function anyway. I understood his question as is the entry token the beginning of the end when he asked "How should I read the graph".